# How to get permission information from EWS by AD name?

Tags: active-directory, exchangewebservices

Dose exchange has method to lookup mailbox by domain account?  (i.e. active directory name)

I would like to create a page to show the authorized mailbox information for particular AD user, but I found that AD name can be different from exchange display name, so dose any current method to check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the email address of the account you are trying to look up, I would suggest using `ResolveName()` method in EWS Managed API, or the `ResolveNames` operation in EWS. This will allow you to give a text sting and get one or more mailboxes returned as a possible match. You can loop through the results until you find the mailbox you need. From there you can bind to the mailbox to get additional information if needed. Here is an example using EWS Managed API:

```
// Resolve the ambiguous name "dan".
NameResolutionCollection resolvedNames = service.ResolveName("dan");

// Output the list of candidates.
foreach (NameResolution nameRes in resolvedNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contact name: " + nameRes.Mailbox.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Contact e-mail address: " + nameRes.Mailbox.Address);
    Console.WriteLine("Mailbox type: " + nameRes.Mailbox.MailboxType);
}
```

Here is the same example using EWS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
           xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <ResolveNames xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
              xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
              ReturnFullContactData="true">
      <UnresolvedEntry>dan</UnresolvedEntry>
    </ResolveNames>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have an article coming out on MSDN soon that will give more details about these examples. For now you can check out the reference topics for the method/operation:

- [ExchangeService.ResolveName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
- [ResolveNames operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563518%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

I hope this helps. If this did resolve your question, please mark the post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have tried this before but some cases it return more than one result to me which is another user, just the name is similar, so it's not correct.

Comment: That's actually the purpose of ResolveName, to give you a list of candidates of possible matches. You can limit the results by specifying where to look (Contacts, AD or both), and you can specify a more unique string to search against.

Comment: An MSDN article was just posted to show how you can resolve ambiguous names. [How to: Resolve ambiguous names by using EWS in Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx)